# vAxis with ticks doesn't work on Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, react-google-charts

https://jsfiddle.net/za1u62cv/13/

Here is my JS Fiddle. I followed the documentation page (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart#data-format) to make it work. I am sure that the format is correct, but the axis formatting doesn't get applied.

Options

```
var options = {
          width: 800,
          height: 500,
          vAxis: 
            {
            "ticks": 
                [{"v":0,"f":"A"},{"v":1,"f":"B"},{"v":2,"f":"C"}]
            },
 };
```

Any help?